# How can I access a char * using the array notation in C?

Tags: c

The title is pretty straight-forward. I want to access a `char *` string using pointer notation. I know I can print the string directly using the derefencing operator. For examsple, I have written the following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void printString(char * str){
    while(*str){
        printf("%c", *str);
        str++;
    }
}

int main(){
    char myString[] = "This is a String.";
    printString(myString);
    return 0;
}
```

This program prints the string correctly. However, if I change my `printString` function to following I get garbage:

```
void printString(char * str){
    int i = 0;
    while(*str){
        printf("%c", *(str+i));
        i++; str++;
    }
}
```

Why does this happen? How can I access the string using the array notation?

Comment: Why do you increment both i and str, one is sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you are incrementing both variables when you should only increment one.

Second, you should check the same condition that you are printing.

```
void printString(char * str){
    int i = 0;
    while(*(str+i)){
        printf("%c", *(str+i));
        i++;
    }
}
```

Third, based on your question title, you want array notation, which looks like the following, and not what you have.

```
void printString(char * str){
    int i = 0;
    while(str[i]){
        printf("%c", str[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Fourth, you can make it more concise with a `for` loop.

```
void printString(char * str){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; str[i]; i++)
        printf("%c", str[i]);
}
```

Comment: Since the title includes the phrase "array notation", might be worth showing how `str[i]` can be used, and is cleaner?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the other array notation too! :-)